# How can I cancel a long-running query using Spring in Cassandra DB?

Tags: java, spring, multithreading, jdbctemplate, cassandra-3.0

How can I cancel a long-running query using Spring Integration Channel and CachedPreparedStatementCreator class in Cassandra DB where simultaneously threads are accessing the DB in a parallel calls  and so as to reduce the time taken for the waiting call to cancel?

I am doing timeouts at the after stages where I am collecting the data in Completables Futures and timing out the Futures and also use custom async threadpool task executor so as to kill the thread after a designated time interval if it goes beyond and also I have applied the Overall DB read timeout and query read timeout.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

By default, the Cassandra Java driver only waits for the coordinator to respond within 2 seconds. Otherwise it throws a `DriverTimeoutException`.

You can configure it by placing an `application.conf` file in the classpath with the following configuration:

```
datastax-java-driver {
  basic.request {
    timeout = 2 seconds
  }
}
```

For details, see the [Java driver Reference Configuration](https://docs.datastax.com/en/developer/java-driver/4.17/manual/core/configuration/reference/). Cheers!